# Passing variable ondrag with HTML slider element

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a function in JS which requires a variable to be passed into it. The actual function in this case doesn't really matter, but I can't figure out how to get it to pass the variable in correctly.

The HTML looks like so -

```
<input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="1.6" step=".1" id="slider" ondrag="callFunction(value)" />
```

Then later on, we describe the function as..

```
<script>
        function callFunction(v)
        {
           ...
        }
</script>
```

The `ondrag="callFunction(value)"` doesn't work as the value is just a string...I have tried concatenating the value on, but it seems to throw up an error.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: try `ondrag="callFunction(this.value)"`

Comment: @Hobroker thanks for the suggestion, this doesn't seem to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd always go about it - namely, attach the event handler via code. When doing so, inside the handler function, the keyword `this` refers to the element on which the event has been fired. So, if we'd like to extract the slider's value or do anything else upon drag here's one way.

```js
"use strict";
function qsa(sel,par=document){return par.querySelectorAll(sel)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded2, false);

function onLoaded2(evt)
{
 byId('slider').addEventListener('input', onSliderInput, false);
}

function onSliderInput(evt)
{
 qsa('span')[0].textContent = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="1.6" step=".1" id="slider"/> Value:<span>1</span>
```